# InDesign: vertical justification button missing

Tags: adobe-indesign

I can't see these buttons in my Control Panel. I'm using: Adobe InDesign CC 2018.

[image: InDesign CC]

[image: InDesign]

Comment: It's also in `Object > Text frame options... (Cmd+B)` → `General (1st tab) > Vertical justification > Align`.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks, I know this method but, using button it's easiest and fastest way .. so.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a 13" laptop, or have some kind of system magnification turned on, or just looking via some sort of small screen device, the InDesign interface gets automatically adjusted and some buttons may be hidden or moved to other places.

There's a flyout menu at the very right edge of the control panel bar, click that and try to switch to a 'Float' view.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but still don't working with me..
:/